# vendor prefixes cause css to fail

Tags: css

I am trying to style the placeholder to an input.  This rule works fine in FF and Chrome:

```
.b-required-missing input[type="text"]::placeholder,
.b-required-missing input[type="email"]::placeholder,
.b-required-missing textarea::placeholder {
     color: tomato;
 }
```

However, if I try to get it to work in Edge using the vendor prefixes for either MS or webkit (I read somewhere that Edge responds to the webkit prefix):

```
.b-required-missing input[type="text"]::-ms-input-placeholder,
.b-required-missing input[type="email"]::-ms-input-placeholder,
.b-required-missing textarea::-ms-input-placeholder,
.b-required-missing input[type="text"]::placeholder,
.b-required-missing input[type="email"]::placeholder,
.b-required-missing textarea::placeholder{
    color: tomato;
}
```

This breaks it in firefox, even if I put the `-moz-` vendor prefix.  How can I get it to work in all 3 browsers?

http://jsfiddle.net/vc8V4/516/

Comment: [Try one `:` instead of two?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:-ms-input-placeholder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browser ignores style if it's rule is invalid.

So `-moz-` is invalid in Chrome.

Instead of use single rule use different for each prefix:

```
.b-required-missing input[type="text"]::-ms-input-placeholder,
.b-required-missing input[type="email"]::-ms-input-placeholder,
.b-required-missing textarea::-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: tomato;
}

.b-required-missing input[type="text"]::placeholder,
.b-required-missing input[type="email"]::placeholder,
.b-required-missing textarea::placeholder{
    color: tomato;
}
```

That way first rule will fail and then second will be applied