# Why is it impossible to stack CSS cross-browsers rules on placeholders?

Tags: css, cross-browser

I'm trying to associate `text-align: center;` to the placeholder of an input, taking account of the browsers compatibility.

Under Chrome, Firefox and Edge, this code doesn't work:

```
#test::-webkit-input-placeholder,
#test:-moz-placeholder, 
#test::-moz-placeholder, 
#test:-ms-input-placeholder {
    text-align: center;
}
```

... And this one, its equivalent in term of code, works:

```
#test::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    text-align: center;
}

#test:-moz-placeholder {
  text-align: center;
}

#test::-moz-placeholder {
  text-align: center;
}

#test:-ms-input-placeholder {
  text-align: center; 
}
```

Why?

Comment: If the browser does not understand a selector, the whole block is discarded. From the spec [_"User agents must observe the rules for handling parsing errors ... the entire rule in which the selector is used is dropped"_](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#Conformance)

Comment: Because if a selector contains an error, the whole rule is ignored. Firefox ignores the rule because the selector contains `::-webkit-input-placeholder`, Chrome ignores it because of the `::-moz-placeholder`. [Here](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#invalid) is the official spec.

Comment: Interesting question, +1

Comment: See also [vendor prefixes cause css to fail](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49196397/1016716).